# Connection manager in windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, connectivity

I try to use the cell core connection manager with c# in order to force my application to browse through the WAP gateway (using its GUID) although the default connection is internet. I see that the WAP connection opens but then all actual requests go through the internet and I end up with 2 open connections. Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using [Connection Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms879580.aspx). There is a .NET wrapper in OpenNetCF Smart Device Framework. Documentation [here](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/). You need to use the Connect method that connects to a specific network, using its GUid.

Comment: But that's exactly what I'm doing, using the connection manager to connect to a specific network using its GUID

Comment: Could you post the code that you are using to make the requests?

Comment: IntPtr connHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
ConnMgrStatus stat;
Guid wapguid = new Guid("{bla-bla}");

ConnMgrConnectionInfo info = new ConnMgrConnectionInfo(wapguid, ConnMgrPriority.UserInteractive, ConnMgrProxy.Http);

ConnectionManager.ConnMgrEstablishConnectionSync(info, ref connHandle, 20000, ref stat);